# Constant variable multiplied with user input

Tags: c++, variables, constants, user-input

I've been trying to create a simple program that allows me to display a total score after the user has entered the ammount of successful hits, `totalHits`, by multiplying that input with the constant variable `POINTS` resulting in another variable; `score`.

I didn't think creating such a program would be any problem, but as usual, I was wrong.. When I run the program `score` is always random, even if I enter '1' as `totalHits` every time. It can differ from 444949349 to -11189181 to name a couple of examples. I have no idea what I've done wrong, so it would be great if someone could give me a clue as to what to do next :)

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int POINTS = 50;
    int totalHits;
    int score = totalHits * POINTS;

    cout << "Please enter the ammount of successful hits: ";
    cin >> totalHits;
    cout << "You hit " << totalHits << " targets, and your ";
    cout << "score is " << score << " ." << endl;

    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() + 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Big thanks to KerrekSB and Paddyd for providing me with the correct answer. Here's the finished code with comments:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int POINTS = 50;
    int totalHits;

    cout << "Please enter the ammount of successful hits: ";
    cin >> totalHits;
    cout << "You hit " << totalHits << " targets, and your ";
    /*As you can see I moved the line below from the top of the code.
    The problem was I had not properly learned how C++ executes the code.
    The orignal code was written in a way that calculates `score` before
    the user could decide it's value, resulting in a different total score than
    it should have been. In the finished code, the user inputs what
    value `totalHits` is, THEN score is calculated by using that value. */
    int score = totalHits * POINTS;
    cout << "score is " << score << " ." << endl;

    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() + 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ programs are executed in order, one statement at a time. C++ is imperative, not declarative. Did you mean to write HTML?

Comment: @KerrekSB Eh, no :S This is supposed to be a C++ program. Are you saying I should relocate some of my lines?

Comment: Yes, though I must say this is a *really* bizarre question. I mean, I can see what you may have been thinking, but that's just not at all how C++ works :-S One statement at a time, and each statement, sequentially, changes the state of the world...

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, do you mind telling me what to place where then? I started like yesterday writing what I believed to be C++ ;) So I'm not sure what to do :)

Comment: 1. read input, 2. multiply input by scale factor, 3. output the result.

Comment: @KerrekSB Wow.... I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a bunch, I'll update the main post with the solution as well.

Comment: If you don't mind me saying, but if this *were* difficult, then this would be a terrible language. Simple problems should have simple solutions. So yes, this is simple, and it should be simple. (This is also a meta-lesson: If you're solving a simple problem and your solution is complex, you've done it wrong, probably.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int totalHits;
int score = totalHits * POINTS;
```

You are multiplying by an uninitialized variable (`totalHits`)! You need to apply a value to totalHits before doing this calculation.

Try using the code like this:

```
const int POINTS = 50;
int totalHits;
int score;

cout << "Please enter the ammount of successful hits: ";
cin >> totalHits;
cout << "You hit " << totalHits << " targets, and your ";
score = totalHits * POINTS;                   //totalHits has a value here
cout << "score is " << score << " ." << endl;

cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() + 2);
return 0;
```

Comment: To store the players score I would imagine. Yes you could just `cout << (totalHits * POINTS)` but the OP was using it so I kept it in.

Comment: @Paddyd Correct. I will be using `score` later as well, so multiplying each time seems like it might get tedious.

Comment: @Rezic yes it would, thats why I left it in